# modify ionic.config.json error The config file (.\ionic.config.json) is not valid JSON format

Tags: ionic-framework

I modified the `ionic.config.json` file and added the "proxy", but when I run the "ionic server", I get the following error message:

> The config file (.\ionic.config.json) is not valid JSON format.

Any suggestions how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

without your json, hard to say

But with your error, seems you have an error in your JSON file. You can check your json file with this website/linter https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: {
  "name": "wellone",
  "app_id": "",
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/v1",
      "proxyUrl": "https://api.instagram.com/v1"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: you have a `;` and not a `,` in your `ProxyUrl` line. Change it and it should work